# Is it possible to disable the 'Activate Windows' screen that appears in Windows 8 at a particular interval of time?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

[image: Activate Windows Nag Screen]

After the installation of Windows 8 I was unable to activate it, because of this at a regular interval of time the 'Activate Windows' screen appears. Is there a way to permanently disable this screen from appearing?

Comment: *> Is there a way to permanently disable this screen from appearing?* Yes, by activating it. What makes you "unable to activate it"? Have you tried calling Microsoft?

Comment: @Bob No I didn't called.

Comment: We're not going to help you with bypassing activation requirements (and therefore violating licence terms). Go activate it properly.

Comment: You should if its a legitimate install - its fairly painless and occationally needed with certain network setups. If its *not* a legitimate install, congratulations, this is *precisely* why windows needs activation. I'd note that if you're running a pirated copy of windows, we don't condone piracy here and this question may be closed and/or get downvoted a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've activated Windows successfully, the activation screen doesn't appear again.
If there are any activation issues, the activation dialog tend to appear again.

Kindly note that the dialog also appears if unconventional or unsupported methods of activation was made.